# Google Map url geocode understanding

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Can any Please explain what **0**(ZERO) represents in geocode parameters of below url,

(geocode=**0**,33.32032770893669,-111.96618234118574)

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=&daddr=7200+West+Ray+Road,+Chandler,+AZ+85226,+USA&geocode=**0**,33.32032770893669,-111.96618234118574
```

Comment: If it's not documented and officially explained, the best we can do is guess; and this guess may become invalid at any time if Google decides to change the use of this parameter in their *private* API. A such, the question is somewhat fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Geocoding API returns an Accuracy value within each returned Placemark `geocode`

This value indicates the resolution of the given result, but not necessarily the correctness of the result. For example, a geocode of "111 8th Avenue, New York, NY" may return 8 (Address) level accuracy, indicating that the geocode is on the order of resolution of a street address. A geocode for "France" would only return 1 (Country) level accuracy.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/#GeocodingAccuracy)

```
geocode=0   Unknown accuracy.
```

Comment: While I think it's a valid guess, the documentation does not specifically talk about *that* particular parameter. You're talking about *results*, while the OP is talking about a *request* parameter.

Comment: see documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/#GeocodingAccuracy

Comment: I did. *"The Google Geocoding API returns an Accuracy value..."* - emphasis on **returns** here; the question is about something that's *sent to* Google.